# Error installing Rails 3.0.3 on Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an old application that runs on a CentOS server with Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.3.

I am trying to install my application on a new DEBIAN 10 server.

I could install Ruby 1.9.2 but when I try to install Rails 3.0.3 with this command, "gem install rails -v 3.0.3", it throws an error saying that "concurrent-ruby requires Ruby version >= 2.3"